# Create a dataframe from a column in multiple excel file in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I have some Excel files, each of them has a column named `Distance`; I want to put all the `Distance` columns into a `dataframe`; I have read them into R in the following way

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
```

Now in `df.list` I have 30 files and I want to create a `dataframe` containing the data in the form `Distance1, Distance2, ..., Distance30` from `df.list`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `do.call("cbind", lapply(df.list, function(x) x[["Distance"]]))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: How can I cbind specific columns of all data frames of a nested loop within the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725995/r-how-can-i-cbind-specific-columns-of-all-data-frames-of-a-nested-loop-within-t)

Answer (score 0):

In Hadleyverse approach:

```
   library(purrr)
    d <- file.list %>% map(readxl::read_excel) %>% map("Distance") %>% set_names(nm = file.list) %>% dplyr::bind_cols()
```